# Store into a single XML file more than one Properties in Java

Tags: java, xml

If I had a Properties instance that I wanted to save to an XML file, I'd just call Properties's storeToXML().

Now I have an array of Properties, which I'd like to store in a single XML file. For each Properties instance in the array, there should be one indentation step in the XML hierarchy. Inside every indentation step for each Properties instance, the XML hierarchy should (could) look like the one that one gets when the storeToXML() method is called.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: easiest way to generate the xml ?? [JAXB Tutoria](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)  , [JAXB Specs](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/release-documentation.html)

Comment: The only ways I could think of doing it would to either merge all the properties into a single object it write it your self (the export)